# Get latitude and longitude from json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

Tell me please, how can I get lat & lon for my rails-app now? -

```
#<HTTParty::Response:0x7fbda4055780 parsed_response={"ip"=>"74.125.232.229", "city"=>{"id"=>5375480, "lat"=>37.38605, "lon"=>-122.08385, "name_ru"=>"Маунтин-Вью", "name_en"=>"Mountain View", "name_de"=>"Mountain View", "name_fr"=>"Mountain View", "name_it"=>"Mountain View", "name_es"=>"Mountain View", "name_pt"=>"Mountain View", "okato"=>"", "vk"=>0, "population"=>74066}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you assign your HTTParty response to a variable like this:

```
r = #<HTTParty::Response:0x7fbda4055780 parsed_response={"ip"=>"74.125.232.229", "city"=>{"id"=>5375480, "lat"=>37.38605, "lon"=>-122.08385, "name_ru"=>"Маунтин-Вью", "name_en"=>"Mountain View", "name_de"=>"Mountain View", "name_fr"=>"Mountain View", "name_it"=>"Mountain View", "name_es"=>"Mountain View", "name_pt"=>"Mountain View", "okato"=>"", "vk"=>0, "population"=>74066}}
```

Then you can grab the parsed response (I like to have it with indifferent access), like this:

```
r = r.parsed_response.with_indifferent_access
```

And then you can do:

```
lat = r[:city][:lat]
lon = r[:city][:lon]
```